# How to distribute DNS queries to many resolvers?

Tags: dns, resolve, dnsmasq

for a research project I want to get the IP addresses of millions of domains. I don't want to overload a single DNS server of course. My idea would be to distribute the queries to a (few) hundred or so open dns resolvers (i.e. from http://public-dns.tk/). How can I do this? Would it be enough to install dnsmasq and add the 100 or so DNS servers to /etc/resolv.conf or would dnsmasq only query the first/second entry of the list? Caching doesn't matter since every domain is only once in the list.
I guess installing a full blown dns server with querying the root server directly is not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the IP/address of DNS server in the dig query, that you fire:

```
dig @<IP_OF_DNS_SERVER> www.google.com
```

Example, below queries go against OpenDNS, and Google DNS respectively:

- dig **@208.67.222.222** www.manish-m.com
- dig **@8.8.8.8** stackoverflow.com